# Requirejs baseurl relative

Tags: plugins, requirejs, base-url

I want to set the baseurl to the folder where Require js is in, which is called js. Now I have this funny/ frustrating phenomenon that when I write

```
require({
        baseUrl: './'
    });
```

It sets the baseUrl to the url from which the document is loaded, when I set it to

```
 require({
        baseUrl: './js'
    });
```

It sets takes sets it the folder [MyProjectfoder]/js/js/ with the second js being "wrong" of course, since I want it to set it relative from my page... Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The reason why I need is is, that I want to load plugins like the text or async plugin, which are taken form the baseurl, so if it is not the right director, the plugins can't be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, when I write `URLs`, I forget which directory it is pointing to.

Try using:

```
require({
     baseUrl: 'js'
 });
```

I hope it helps. If not, just leave a comment.

Comment: Yes, it worked :). I hade some dependecies to js in other libraries, but now it looks fine thank you